# Have Visual Studio SQL print out employee names only once

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I am using SQL to reference two databases, Permissions and Recognize, to be able to print out an employees full name. The problem is, the Recognize database, has duplicates of the employees, and my SQL query ends up printing the name multiple times because of it. I am trying to print out the names of the different content mangers from three separate regions. Here is what I want it to say:

```
Content Manager: Bob Smith
Content Manager: Sarah Jones
Content Manager: David Lee
```

Instead, because there are multiple entries in the data base, it prints this:

```
Content Manager: Bob Smith
Content Manager: Bob Smith
Content Manager: Bob Smith
Content Manager: Bob Smith
Content Manager: Sarah Jones
Content Manager: Sarah Jones
Content Manager: Sarah Jones
Content Manager: David Lee
Content Manager: David Lee
```

Here is the code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource25" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IntranetDB %>"
SelectCommand="
SELECT
    Permissions.id,
    Permissions.username,
    Permissions.grouping, 
    Permissions.isContentManager, 
    Permissions.CMRegion, 
    Recognize.give, 
    Recognize.receive,
    Recognize.fullnameGive, 
    Recognize.fullnameReceive, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Permissions.username = Recognize.give THEN Recognize.fullnameGive
        WHEN Permissions.username = Recognize.receive THEN Recognize.fullnameReceive 
        END AS Expr1
    FROM Permissions
    INNER JOIN Recognize
        ON Permissions.username = Recognize.give 
        OR Permissions.username = Recognize.receive
    WHERE
        (Permissions.grouping = 'design')
    AND (Permissions.isContentManager = 'yes')
    AND (Permissions.CMRegion is not null)">     
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView17" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource25">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" SortExpression="id" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="Content Manager" visible="false" SortExpression="username" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="grouping" HeaderText="grouping" Visible="False" SortExpression="grouping" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="isContentManager" HeaderText="isContentManager" Visible="False" SortExpression="isContentManager" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr1" HeaderText="Content Manager" Visible="True" SortExpression="Expr1" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CMRegion" HeaderText="Region" Visible="True" SortExpression="CMRegion" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Review your JOINs or apply SELECT DISTINCT..

Comment: I did try adding SELECT DISTINCT to it, and unfortunately it did not change anything

Comment: Remove fields from `Recognize` in the `SELECT` statement and then do `DISTINCT`. See the explanation below.

Comment: Also, instead of joining Recognize with an OR, join with Recognize with Permission twice.

Answer (score 0):

From the result, it seems like `Bob Smith` has multiple 4 recognitions (`Recognize`) and `Sarah Jones` has 3. When joining two tables:

```
SELECT A.Name, B.give
FROM Permissions A
JOIN Recognize B ON A.KeyField = B.FKKeyField
```

If B has multiple rows matching with table A, you will get:

```
Name        Give
Bob Smith   A
Bob Smith   B
Bob Smith   C
Bob Smith   D
Sarah Jones X
Sarah Jones Y
Sarah Jones Z
```

Even if you print just the `Name` in your UI, they will appear multiple times.

If you don't need to print the recognitions, don't add the field in `SELECT` and perform a `DISTINCT`.

Also, you might want to reconsider how you are joining. Joining with OR is not a good idea.

```
SELECT
    R.give, 
    R.receive,
    R.fullnameGive, 
    R.fullnameReceive, 

    PG.id as GiverId,
    PG.username AS GiverUserName,

    PR.id as RecepientId,
    PR.username AS RecepientUserName

    FROM Recognize R
    JOIN Permissions PG
        ON PG.username = R.give
    JOIN Permissions PR
        ON PR.username = R.receive
```